# Rails: Load default image if image_tag cannot load image from url

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to render a default image if image_tag cannot load an image from a url:

So if image_tag cannot load image from url:

```
<%= image_tag 'https://something.com/image.jpg' %>
```

then render default:

```
<%= image_tag image_url("default.png")
```

Comment: maybe you should take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928989/replacing-broken-external-images-with-custom-image

Answer (score 12):

#### Use the `onerror` attribute in the `img` tag.

```
<%= image_tag 'https://something.com/image.jpg', 
      src: 'Image Not Found', 
      onerror: 'this.error=null;this.src="default.png"' %>
```

This will generate the resulting HTML:

```
<img src='https://something.com/image.jpg' 
  alt="Image not found" 
  onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='default.png';" />
```

Comment: Just as an addition to this, if you want to just hide the image altogether, you can use something like this: `onerror: "this.style.display='none'"`

Answer (score 5):

A pure Ruby on Rails solution:

```
<%= image_tag 'devices/my-device.png' rescue image_tag 'devices/unknow-device.png' %>
```